# How to use Arduino with BLE Shield search Apple's iBeacons signal source

Tags: ios7, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am playing a project to search iBeacons in region by Arduino with BLE Shield.

Because of leak of tech-support of iBeacons Technology, I can't find any docs about how to search iBeacons signal source.

Answer (score 0):

An iBeacon is basically a BLE Broadcaster, and such devices can only be discovered by a Central or an Observer. Many BLE shields use Nordic Semiconductor's nRF8001 chip, and unfortunately, this is a pure Peripheral device, and as such, it isn't possible to use this to discover an iBeacon.

Take a look at [this question](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/what-is-a-client-and-server-in-ble) for further details on the roles in BLE.