# Receiving iBeacon signal by RFduino

Tags: arduino, ibeacon, rfduino

I am working on project with iBeacon tag and RFduino board (is an Arduino variant).

My mission is to receive iBeacon signal info (RSSI) on my RFduino.

First I did, was to test if I can receive data by the RFduino with the following code and it works fine, it receives Bluetooth LE data.

But I do not know how to receive iBeacon data information.

**My Question:** is it possible to receive iBeacon signal (RSSI) or any iBeacon info by RFduino if Yes, How? if No then is it possible to receive iBeacon signal using normal Arduino with HC-05 board (regular Bluetooth board)?

**The code**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RFduinoBLE.deviceName = "device1";
  RFduinoBLE.begin();
}

void loop() {

}

void RFduinoBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len)
{
  Serial.println(data[0]);
}
```

RFduino reference [link](http://www.rfduino.com/product/rfd22102-rfduino-dip/index.html).

[image: The idea of the question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time research AND try and fail, the short answer **NO**.

### More details

iBeacon is basically a Bluetooth LE Broadcaster and it can only be discovered by a Central or an Observer.

Many Bluetooth LE devices here including RFduino device is a pure Peripheral device, it is not possible to use it to discover an iBeacon.

At the other hand you can make RFduino as iBeacon (transmitter), but that won't change the fact it neither have the ability to receive iBeacon announcements nor pass it to other devices.

### Few links for my answer conclusion

- [Receive BLE signal from iBeacon to Bluno(arduino with BLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625572/receive-ble-signal-from-ibeacon-to-blunoarduino-with-ble?rq=1)
- [How to use Arduino with BLE Shield search Apple's iBeacons signal source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374865/how-to-use-arduino-with-ble-shield-search-apples-ibeacons-signal-source)
- https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/232/what-is-a-client-and-server-in-ble/